# Error with memory allocation

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int main(void)
{
    // create a node
    node* list1 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* list2 = malloc(sizeof(node));
    list1 -> n = 2; 
    list2 -> n = 5;
    list1 -> next = list2;
    list2 -> next = NULL;

    if(search(5, list1))
        printf("True\n");
    else
        printf("False\n");

}
```

In the above program, when I initialized variables of type node I had to explicitly allocate memory for those variables otherwise the compiler was throwing errors.

```
bool search(int n, node* list)
{
    node* ptr = list;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(ptr -> n == n)
        {
            return true;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but, in the above function "search" I have a variable of type node "ptr" but i got through without explicitly allocating memory for it. Why there are no errors with this function?

Comment: did you miss the `node* ptr = list;` part?

Comment: You have to assign a value to a pointer variable before you attempt to use it.  In `main`, there were no allocated nodes, so you had to allocate them with `malloc`.  In `search`, you're passing one of those as an argument, and assigning it to `ptr`.  So `ptr` initially points to the node that was passed to it.  I'm guessing you copied this code and are trying to understand it?

Answer (score 4):

It would be a good idea to add the warning in your Q. However, I assume that it is something like "uninitialized variable".

As mentioned in the comments by pm100 you maybe get a runtime error, when the program is executed. However, it has the same reason.

"Initialized" does not mean "assign allocated memory", but assign any value to it. In `search()` you do this correctly right here:

```
node* ptr = list;
```

In `main()` you do not do this, if you have solely:

```
node* list1; // No initialization
```

BTW: A compiler can detect if you assign `NULL` to it and then dereference it with `->`. So there might be an error, if you have a code like this:

```
node* list1 = NULL;
list1 -> n = 2; // Dereferencing NULL pointer constant
```

But whether a compiler detects that or not depends on him. Again, at runtime you will get an error in either case.

Comment: my guess is that the 'compiler throwing errors' was actually runtime crash

Comment: Oh, possible, too.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a variable of type node "ptr" but i got through without explicitly allocating memory for it. Why there are no errors with this function?

`ptr` is not type `node`.  Code has a variable called `ptr` which is a **pointer** to type `node`.

The following code created the space for the *pointer*.

```
node* ptr = list;
```